# Why should be used in twice "new" in systemverilog?

Tags: system-verilog

Would you let me know why do we have to have the "new" keyword in twice in systemverilog?
​

```
 class MyClass;
   int number; 
   function new(); 
     number = 0; 
   endfunction
 endclass

 module test;
   MyClass test1 = new();
 endmodule
```

As you can see, there are used in twice "new" keyword.

Could you let me know why do we need to use in twice?

Answer (score 1):

```
function new();
    number = 0; 
endfunction
```

provides implementation of the function `new()`. When we call:

`MyClass test1 = new();`

we are creating `test1`. In order to create it, we call function `new()`, whose implementation we defined above. When we call `new()` it will ensure that property `number` of `test1` is initialized to 0 (because that is what is happening inside of `new()`).

I hope my explanation is clear.